# Rails design pattern: multiple "perspectives" of the same object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, design-patterns

I have a Project, which can bee seen by Manager, Contractor, Worker etc. Each of these roles can see some part of a project but not the other. Furthermore, some actions won't be available for past projects.

I currently have one view for each role and conditional on project status. That's a lot of views. How should I DRY it up?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about permissions for each role (for example `Ability` in [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan)), and then using those permissions on each relevant attribute of `Project`? You'd have conditional code for every field/attribute, but at least you only have to write it once.